# Result summary report in python nosetests

Tags: python, nose, nosetests

Im using nosetests command to execute python files, and i often run 100+ python files in one shot, many a times test case file will be skipped based on the @attr value. Is there plugin available to get the summary of the test case result or summary some thing like below

```
Test1 --> passed
Test2 --> failed
Test3 --> error
Test4 --> skipped
```

Comment: You mean like the Xunit-formatted output you get from the Xunit plugin, or the terminal output you get from changing the verbosity you run nose with?

Comment: ive not used it to know the format, does it provide in HTML format?

Comment: Chaning verbosity didn't help, it won't report test case result summary

Comment: Xunit is an XML-based format.  Changing the verbosity will give you a rollup of results, but it will dump it to stdout/stderr.  There's also the HTMLTestRunner package available from PyPI that you could try.

Comment: Thank you, tried using it, didn't produce any output
used like this
`nosetests --exe --nologcapture --cover-html --cover-html-dir=/path/To/Folder /path/To/Folder/file.py`

Comment: Looking at the sample report produced by this module, it generates are the coverage report of each and every module used in the test cae file. (http://tungwaiyip.info/software/sample_test_report.html). But is there a way to just print the stats for the test case file as mentioned in the question?

Comment: Did you try expanding any of the details or clicking "all"?  It's all there...

Comment: You should be using `--with-xunit` and `--xunit-file` instead of coverage to enable [http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/xunit.html xunit] plugin.

Comment: @Oleksiy, as i told before, i only wanted to see TCs verdict, it captures everything which goes in console

Comment: specially I'm more worried about skipped Test cases, as this is not captured now

Answer (score 2):

Nostest results can be output to XML using the Xunit parameter:

If you enter the following at the command line:

```
$ nosetests --help
```

This give a range of options for nosetests, including the required parameter, i.e:

```
--with-xunit
```